# Why is my Linear Regression Score so low?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction

Took a scrape of the Pgatour.com site where stats are updated regularly. They have historic data going back to 2010 that was scraped to a flat csv file.
Read that in with pd.read_csv(filename) successfully. This scrape is 2010-2019.

```
SG_P    SG_T    SG_TTG  SG_OTT  SG_ATG  POINTS
7   0.243   1.195   0.952   0.338   0.168   718.0
8   0.098   1.192   1.091   0.724   0.260   445.0
9   -0.147  1.001   1.151   0.185   0.738   843.0
11  0.054   0.984   0.927   0.151   0.507   718.0
12  0.137   1.156   1.014   0.403   0.642   500.0
```

After reforming a new dataframe where I only retain 'SG' stats or 'Strokes-Gained' which have a non-linear relationship to inform golfer's 'Points', we ran a train_test_split of 0.33% for test data.  The target variable is 'POINTS'.

In other [Kaggle runs of this project](https://www.kaggle.com/djdiroff/on-the-strokes-gained-statistics-on-the-pga-tour), the results are usually in the .70 accuracy range.

For a straight Linear Regression from Scikitlearn, mine are in the .25-.30 range which produces very underfitted data which when plotted with Seaborn shows a poor result.

```
training set r^2 score = 0.2601442196444287
testing set r^2 score = 0.2602966900574226
```

The linear regression code goes like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Split features and target

X = df2.iloc[: ,:-1] # Get the features minus OWGR which is the target
y = df2.iloc[:,-1:]  # Just get the target

# Train test split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.33,random_state=12)

lr = LinearRegression(n_jobs = -1,normalize=True)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

training set r^2 score = 0.2601442196444287
testing set r^2 score = 0.2602966900574226
```

Here is the poly version:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

degree = 2 # Start with 2
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree, include_bias=False)

X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X) # No longer a pandas dataframe
y_poly = y # Still a pandas dataframe

X_poly_train, X_poly_test, y_poly_train, y_poly_test = train_test_split(X_poly, y_poly, random_state=12)

lr_poly = LinearRegression()
lr_poly.fit(X_poly_train, y_poly_train)

training set r^2 score = 0.2902297270799855
testing set r^2 score = 0.1746156333412796
```

In the benchmark notebook on Kaggle, I was seeing results like this:

Linear:

```
training set r^2 score = 0.5540673510136147
testing set r^2 score = 0.510807136771844
```

Poly:

```
training set r^2 score = 0.7466513181026075
testing set r^2 score = 0.6325248963195537
```

Comment: Welcome to machine learning, there is not one solution to solve this problem! This is your task now, you can select different features, change the regression method etc. Time to read a book about ML and go on!

Comment: Yes, we are all continuously learning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data preprocessing is a really important previous step to training. Is in this step where data is transformed in order to reduce irrelevant and redundant information, treat invalid values, etc. Some operations regarding data preprocessing may include null values handling, data dimensionality reducing, data standarization, etc. Without performing this process, you may end up having powerful well-designed classifier that performs poorly with your actual data. Try it and probably your results will improve!

Comment: Alex, that is why I am stumped. The same data within exactly the same range in the Kaggle kernel mentioned, has not had any transformations or pre-processing other than dropping columns  and removing observations with NaNs. I tried to reproduce it by using a different scraper than the one they used.  That is really the only difference.  Appreciate your suggestions.  Cheers.

Comment: After some prodding from this group, I found my issue and solved it. What I did was re-wrote the scraper to capture the AVG POINTS from PGA.com and include it in the dataset. Dropping every stat other than the Shots Gained numbers and AVG Points, I re-ran both regressions and was able to reproduce the results from the Kaggle kernel. It did turn out to be a data related issue that required rethinking about scaling and data relevance for this project. Cheers!